# Print Preview Blank IE8

Tags: windows-xp, printing, internet-explorer-8

On a Windows XP, in IE8 print preview always appears completely blank except for header information.

I can open the generated temp file in firefox and print it from there.

I have tried browsing without addons to no success.

I have tried re-creating the "%TEMP%\low" folder as described on the web, e.g. here:

http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/ie/forum/ie8-windows_xp/ie8-printing-does-not-work-preview-empty/920588e5-ccc4-4e24-83d6-606d5e3b1c70

... all with no success.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the end - I reinstalled IE8 (I didn't realise this was possible any more).

Print Preview works again. Link is here: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/318378

Comment: Ben, it's common practice here to accept your own answer if it solved your problem.

Answer (score 1):

To resolve this behavior you can use **IEFIx** http://windowsxp.mvps.org/IEFIX.htm that fix such issues.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion - but it didn't work - (although I didn't have the disks to hand)